# How to define a function for a recursive loop command in Python by using LEX and YACC?

Tags: python, parsing, yacc, lex, context-free-grammar

I'm trying to define a specific grammar for commands shown down below:

- **F n** (go forward n units)
- **R n** (turn right n degrees)
- **L n [ … ]** (repeat commands inside parenthesis n times)
- **COLOR f** (f = line color and colors are: K: red, Y: green, M: blue, S:
  black)  (defines color of the line)
- **PEN n** (n = line thickness) (1: thin, 2: medium, 3: thick) (defines
  thickness of the line)

Here is an example command:

```
L 36 [L 4 [F 100 R 90] R 10]
```

Output:

[image: output of the example command]

Here is the grammar I defined:

```
<start> ::= <function> | <option> 
<function> ::= <forward> | <right> | <loop> | <color> | <pen>
<option> ::= <function> <start> | ε
<forward> ::= F <numbers> 
<right> ::= R <numbers>
<loop> ::= L <numbers> [ <start> ]
<color> ::= COLOR <colors>
<pen> ::= PEN <numbers>
<colors> ::= M | K | S | Y
```

I tried to call *start* non-terminal in _loop function I defined:

```
def p_loop(p):
    'loop : LOOP NUMBER LSQB grammar RSQB'
    
    p[0]=loop_(p[2])

def loop_(x):
    i=1
    while i<=x:
        p_grammar(p)
        i=i+1
```

And it did'nt work.

Then, I tried this:

```
def p_loop(p):
    'loop : LOOP NUMBER LSQB start RSQB '
    i=1
    while i<=p[2]:
        p[0]=p[4]

def p_start(p):
    '''start : function 
             | option'''
    p[0]=p[1]

def p_function(p):
    '''
    function : forward
             | right
             | loop
             | color
             | pen
    '''
    p[0]=p[1]
```

It didn't work properly too. I cannot find another solution. So, how can I define a function for the L command?

[Here](https://github.com/euleriscoding/A-Parsing-Trial) are project codes if you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between two different concepts: *parsing* (or compilation) and *evaluation* (or execution).

Parsing takes as input a textual representation of a program and produces a data object more suitable for repeated evaluation. Evaluation takes the object produced by the parser and uses it to run the program -- in this case, to draw a picture.

Except in very simple cases (such as calculators which have no loops or conditionals), these two procedures are separated, both in time and in logic. First, you use one program (or function) to parse the input and create the executable; then you set the parser aside and use a completely different program (or function) to evaluate the result.

It should be clear from thinking about how loops work. By definition, a loop is executed several times. But it is only parsed once. So how could it be executed during the parse?

One way, of course, would be to parse the body of the loop over and over again. Some scripting languages do that. But it requires a very different parsing framework, because the Ply (or yacc) framework assumes that you will just do a single pass over the input, so it doesn't keep the already parsed text anywhere. Anyway, it's really a waste of cycles to parse the same text more than once.

So the parse needs to produce a data structure which can be executed, and therefore each production's semantic value must be a data object which fits somewhere in this data structure. Thus, your first task is to design the data structure you want use. In fact, I would have recommended doing that *before* you wrote the parser, because it tells you what the parser's result has to be.

There are a number of possible data structures which can be used; it's possible that your assignment has a clear suggestion. Probably this was discussed in the lectures or reading material as well (and if it wasn't and you paid for the course, I'd say you have a reasonable complaint). Two common possibilities are:

- A recursive collection of objects, often referred to as an "abstract syntax tree" because it abstracts from the syntax. Calling this a "tree" is a bit misleading. Although you could implement it from a general purpose tree data object using node attributes to hold relevant information, that's usually more complicated than defining a collection of classes, each of which implements a simple interface. An `evaluate` method might be all that you need, although for debugging you might also want to implement a method which prints the object in some convenient format.
- A list of low-level instructions which could be evaluated by a virtual machine. Commands like `LEFT` and `RIGHT` would just be a simple instructions, which could possibly be tuples of two elements (an opcode and an integer operand). To implement loops, the virtual machine would require a stack; a simple design might be something like this:

  ```
  [0] PUSH  36     # Pushes 36 onto the stack
  [1] PUSH   4     # Body of the outer loop; pushes 4
  [2] FWD  100
  [3] RIGHT 90
  [4] LOOP   2     # '2' is the index of the loop body
  [5] FWD   10
  [6] LOOP   1
  ```

  The `LOOP` instruction decrements the integer at the stop of the stack. If it is non-zero, it continues executing with the instruction whose index is the argument; otherwise, the top element of the stack is 0 and the `LOOP` instruction pops that off the stack and continues with the next instruction in sequence.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I understood what you mean. Your answer is great but I'm not able to understand that right now. I'm studying on this assignment for hours and my brain literally wants to stop. Thus, may I ask you to explain what should I do exactly? Should I use AST or stack? If I use one of them, how can I define a function for loop command?

Comment: Also, you mentioned parsing but In fact, I already got parser and lexer part done and even you were the one who helped me. If you check the link above, you can see my progress on the code. I think there is only one problem and it is handling the loop.

Comment: @euler: both will work fine. If your course doesn't provide any guidance, just choose one. They're both pretty simple. If you're comfortable with object orientation, the AST is probably the more flexible solution. But virtual machines are very common, too.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I'll try AST. So, let's say I used AST solution then would it be necessary to define a function with a while or for loop to make to loop work?

Comment: @euler: The `evaluate` method in the `loop` object would repeatedly call the `evaluate` method of each element of the list of objects in its body. How else could you evaluate the body multiple times?

Comment: I never used `evaluate` before but as I know, `evaluate` parses the expression argument due to the python syntax and runs it. So, you said that I should use `evaluate` method in a `loop` object I'll define and I think it's one of the object I'll define for AST. Then, the loop object would repeatedly call the evaluate method of each element of objects in body. So, code needs a `loop` object and another objects in it's body and `evaluate` method would call the other `evalute` methods. I'm trying to get but my brain is full. Are all these I said correct? If it's not, can you be more specific?

Comment: And, I know I wanted too much things but can you share me a descriptive source about AST and `evaluate`?

Comment: I'm not talking about python's built-in `eval` method. I'm talking about how you organize your objects.

Comment: @euler: Did your college really just give you this assignment without any indication at all about how to solve it? That seems cruel and unusual. I'd file a formal complaint. If, on the other hand, they gave you some resources, you should use them. They're paid to do that. I'm not. I don't even know what your preferred language is.

Comment: Ok, you're right. I'm sorry for taking your time. The college only taught pushdown automaton, parsing (but not the coding process) and parse trees, some grammar types like CFG and BNF. So, there was no programming phase that I could refer to. Sorry, again.

Comment: For what it's worth, I always recommend [SICP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs), which is freely available online. However, it's probably way too late to read a textbook on the subject :-) And it won't help you code. But it does thoroughly explore what evaluation means. That's a fundamental concept, so it's a bit depressing how little emphasis it gets in CS education.

Comment: @Euler: the programs you've written before just do one thing. But now you're being asked to write something like a computer. A computer doesn't just do one thing. It interprets instructions. The essence of a computer is a processing unit whose only job is to take a collection of instructions and execute (or evaluate) them. The instructions are not executed when they're stored in the computer's memory. That's what you need to implement at this point. You need a program which knows how to interpret instructions. So the first thing you need is a way to store the instructions it will interpret.

Comment: Once you do that, you need to consider how to interpret each instruction. If you break it down like that, each individual step is really simple. But you need to keep focussed on the task at hand.

Comment: Thanks a lot, again. Believe me I'm trying to learn, not asking for exact code. I'm writing AST now there are some issues in my brain that I can't figure out. All articles about that use AST import. I don't want to use the import if it's possible, can you share an article?